# taking an integral without trigonometric substitution

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I needed to evaluate $$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx$$
I looked around and found it's solved by trigonometric substitution $x = a\tan\theta$ and the answer is $\frac{\pi}{a}$. I understand the derivation but have been curious: supposing I didn't know the "trick", are there more staightforward methods (even if more laborious) to find this integral?

For example, I figured out the power series $$\frac{1}{x^2+a^2} = \frac{1}{a^2} - \frac{1}{a^4}x^2 + \frac{1}{a^6}x^4 - ...$$

I can integrate the power series term-by-term. But what I end up with obviously diverges as $x\to \infty$ or $x \to -\infty$. Is there a way to continue with this approach and end up with the value of the integral? Or some other way, perhaps?

Comment: Note that there is a restriction when you apply the series expansion.

Comment: "straightforward" I'd say no, but as other users have shown there are alternatives. Although as @ultralegend5385 said be careful with series expansions due to their "radius of convergence"

Answer (score 5):

Consider an upper half semicircular contour and note that those integrals vanishes.

Denote $f(z)=\frac{1}{z^2+a^2}$

Now,  find the pole of the given function and see that it has two poles which are $z=\pm ia$ but only $z=ia$ lies on upper half plane, hence residue is $R=(z-ia)f(z)\bigg|_{z=ia}= \frac{1}{2ia}$.

Now, apply the Residue Theorem, you will find
$I=2\pi i \cdot \frac{1}{2ia}= \frac{\pi}{a}$

Answer (score 5):

You have the right motivation, just use a clever substitution to justify the power series.
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}&\overset{x=at}{=}\frac1a\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\\
&=\frac2a\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}\\
&=\underbrace{\frac2a\int_0^1\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}_{x=t}+\underbrace{\frac2a\int_1^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}}_{x=\frac1t}\\
&=\frac2a\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}+\frac2a\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x^2}\\
&=\frac4a\int_0^1(1-x^2+x^4-x^6+\dots)dx\\
&=\frac4a\left(1-\frac13+\frac15-\frac17+\dots\right)\\
&=\frac4a\times\frac\pi4\\
&=\boxed{\frac\pi a}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Another approach is as follows:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty\frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx 
&= 2\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}dx \\
&= \frac{2}{a^2} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+(x/a)^2}dx \\
&= \frac{2}{a} \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{1+t^2}dt \\
&= \frac{2}{a} \arctan t\bigg|_0^\infty  \\
&= \frac{\pi}{a}\end{align}$$
Note that if $a = 0$, the integral diverges.

Comment: You're implicitly using that substitution to integrate $\displaystyle\int_0^\infty\frac{dt}{1+t^2}$.

Comment: @Martund Perhaps, but the only reason to use an explicit trig substitution here is when the student doesn't recognize the integrand as being essentially the derivative of what is (in calculus) a known function. This is more direct than a substitution approach.